# Contenteditable attribute in a foreignobject doesn't work on firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <foreignObject width="100" height="100" x="20" y="65">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <p contenteditable="true">text</p>
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

This code works in chromium 44 but not (the text is not editable) in firefox 40. Why ?

Comment: It works for me in FF 40.0.3 (meaning I can edit text).

Comment: It works with the "run code snippet" of this site but if you paste this code in a file and open this file on firefox, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Change the file so that it has a .html extension and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firefox engine doesn't bother with processing `contentEditable` when the file is explicitly specified to be XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713919/contenteditable-on-nodes-in-a-xml-compound-document). If you use `text/html` content type (or save your snippet in a file with .html extension), you'll get editable text in Firefox.